# mysql / case / when / then

Tags: mysql, case

Can you help me please.

Where I have error in the following mysql query?

```
SELECT *,
CASE
    WHEN vat = '1' THEN '1.10'
    WHEN vat = '2' THEN '1.21'
END AS _vat,
CASE
    WHEN sleva_kc != '' AND sleva_procent = '' THEN ((cena - sleva_kc) * _vat) 
    WHEN sleva_kc = '' AND sleva_procent != '' THEN ((cena * (1 - (sleva_procent / 100))) * _vat)
    WHEN sleva_kc = '' AND sleva_procent = '' THEN (cena * _vat) END AS _cena
FROM kws_produkty WHERE _cena >= '100' AND _cena <= '500'
```

I use mysql connector:

- @mysql_connect(HOST, USER, PASS)

explanation:

- vat = VAT
- cena = price
- sleva_kc = Amount of discount in cash
- sleva_procent = Amount of discount in percent

I need get output:

- _cena = price with DISCOUNT and VAT (DISCOUNT can be a percentage or amount, VAT can be higher or smaller)

Thank you.

Comment: what is the error message you're getting?

Comment: Theses cases - should the result be returned or is this some kind of filtering the records? The syntax is very wrong.

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN vat = '1' THEN '1.10' WHEN vat = '2' THEN '1.21' END AS _vat, CASE whe' at line 1. I'm a beginner in mysql.

Comment: It's as simple as `ELSE cena`, if moved into `SELECT` part of this query.

Comment: @jurkix You've got to use a comma between `*` and the first `CASE`, correct the `ELSEIF`

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is COMPLETELY mangled. You have your `case` statements in a place where they cannot be used and you are using `elseif` but do have have an `if` statement going.

```
SELECT
   CASE .... END CASE,
   IF ... THEN ... ELSEIF ... END IF
FROM yourtable
WHERE ....
```

I suggest you start reading the syntax documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `CASE WHEN ... END` expressions should be part of the field list - before your `FROM`-clause.

The use of a column alias name in the `WHERE`-clause is illegal, see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-alias.html):

Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.